# How to set page range in android print dialog programmatically

Tags: android, printing, android-print-framework

I am working on a pdf printing app and got stuck when I am asked to set the page range using android PrintDocumentAdapter. I am setting the page range using android api like this

```
this.printManager.print(FilenameUtils.getName(pdfPath),
            new PrintDocumentAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages,
                        ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                        CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                        WriteResultCallback callback) {
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destination
                            .getFileDescriptor());
                                            InputStream pdfInStream = null;
                    try {
                        pdfInStream = new FileInputStream(
                                PdfPrint.this.pdfPath);
                        IOUtils.copy(pdfInStream, output);

                        callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[] {new PageRange(0, 1), new PageRange(2, 4)});

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {

                        try {
                            output.flush();
                            pdfInStream.close();
                            output.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
```

still the print dialog appears with the "All" option and here I can also set the range manually. But I want to restrict this behavior as I am setting the page range programmatically and dialog should appear with page range which have been set earlier and print only those specific pages. Is there any way to disable this "Manually Page Range Selection" and set the page range on appear of print dialog.
Please help me

Comment: How many pages do you have? Your array is printing pages 0-4. If you have only 5 pages, this ranges will consider them all.

Comment: I have 7 pages in that PDF and I am able to print the specific pages by keeping the page range manually but the problem comes Print dialog not showing the page range which i have set it is still showing "All" option

Answer (score 0):

The [`onWriteFinished`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback.html?hl=en#onWriteFinished(android.print.PageRange%5B%5D)) callback signals the pages that were actually written to `destination`. Your code sends the whole PDF so it should provide:

```java
callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[] { PageRange.ALL_PAGES });
```

To constrain the print to certain pages, send a PDF that contains only those pages.